# I have this code that I have done but I dont get the code to work as I want in Python

Tags: python

I have this code that I have made and I wonder where is the problem. It should be an age calculator that use a list called YOB "Year of Birth" and I want to read values from my list to count youngest age, oldest age and middle age from the years in my list. But when it counts middle age is 636.1428xxxxxxx and youngest be 21 and the oldest 2096. Now I know that the youngest should be 21 and the oldest 87 and middle age should be 49.

```py
import datetime
import statistics

counts = 0
sumYear = 0
oldAge = 0
youngAge = 110
YOB = [1999, 1932, 1887, 1982, -76, 1963, 0]

for years in YOB:
    years = datetime.datetime.now().year - years
    if years > 0:
        counts += 1
        sumYear += years
    if years < youngAge:
        youngAge = years
        print('Test3')
    if years > oldAge:
        oldAge =  years
        print('test4')

print("middle age is ", sumYear / counts, "year.")
print("the youngest are", youngAge, " and the oldest are ", oldAge)
```

Comment: For one thing, you're iterating over `for years in...` but also setting `years=` inside the loop, which may lead to unexpected issues

Comment: Please improve the title, and see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Yes, I have done breakpoint that is the best way to find and also to see whare the wrong is in my code. but becouse Iam a novis in Python I do not know the solution to my problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Presuming -76 and 0 aren't valid birth years, your oldest person is 133 (born in 1887). 
You can ignore the -76 and 0 birth year people by putting the if clauses that change the youngAge and oldAge variables to be under the year checker. I also changed the variable you pass to year to keep the definition of years to a single meaning (just the age) and the YOB iterables to just the year they were born.

```
### Summary of Ages for birth years
import datetime
import statistics

counts = 0
sumYear = 0
oldAge = 0
youngAge = 110
YOB = [1999, 1932, 1887, 1982, -76, 1963, 0]

for year in YOB:
    years = datetime.datetime.now().year - year
    print(year, years)
    if year > 0:
        counts += 1
        sumYear += years
        if years < youngAge:
            youngAge = years
            print('Test3')
        if years > oldAge:
            oldAge =  years
            print('test4')

print("middle age is ", sumYear / counts, "year.")
print("the youngest are", youngAge, " and the oldest are ", oldAge)
```

Comment: Hi David. Thank you for your help. Now I see what change you made and how. I understand now what happening in my code. =)